# Pandas average per timeslot over different days, then sum within hour

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, aggregation

I have a question about pandas and working with time series.
I get my data as a json from an API, the data includes traffic counts on different locations, measured every 5 minutes. The simplified data looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "123",   // location id
    "date": "2020-01-01T00:45:00Z",   // date and time 
    "intensity": 7   // number of vehicles counted
  },
...
]
```

There is a month's worth of data, read using pandas and concatenated into one big dataframe:

```py
# in loop:
  dfs = []
  df = pd.read_json(de.path)
  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
  dfs.append(df)
data = pd.concat(dfs)
```

I average the counts for equivalent time slots over different days:

```py
data = data.set_index('date')
data = data.groupby(df.index.time).aggregate("mean")
```

The final step is where I have a problem. I have tried using the pandas.resample function, but that requires a TimeDateIndex, which is lost in the previous step - if I print the index out, I get this:

```
print(data.index)
>>> Index([00:00:00, 00:05:00, 00:10:00, 00:15:00, 00:20:00, 00:25:00, 00:30:00,
       00:35:00, 00:40:00, 00:45:00,
       ...
       23:10:00, 23:15:00, 23:20:00, 23:25:00, 23:30:00, 23:35:00, 23:40:00,
       23:45:00, 23:50:00, 23:55:00],
      dtype='object', length=288)
```

I tried converting the index to PeriodIndex, but failed.

Is there a common way of doing this? I feel I have probably missed something simple.

Comment: Can we see some sample data and the code to reproduce the problem? You are doing `data = pd.concat(dfs)` but then are referencing df: `df = df.set_index('date')` Are you working with the correct variable. You also have `df['dateObserved']` in your loop but are using a column called `date` later. None of which are keys in your sample json.

Comment: Ah I changed some of the code but not all. Let me fix this. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the `groupby` function by like this:

```py
for i, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 12):
    counts_by_name[name].append((i+1, sum(g['intensity'])))
```

Does anyone know of a nicer solution that would allow actual resampling?